# GnuPG v1.4.10 cant read

Tags: launchpad, gnupg, openpgp

I was thinking of "Getting Involved" with Ubuntu and decided to join the Bug Squad. After a few steps of joining, I got an email with a OpenPGP key licenced at Gnu version 1.4.10 and went on their website. They recommended me a couple of apps that can decode the code, but none of them worked, in fact each of them said that the code is corrupted. I thought that there's something wrong with that email, so I resent the request. As I got another email and tried the code with those programs, the programs said the same thing. How can I decode the code properly? Is there an online website that would be able to convert it?? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the message (first line "-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----" and last "-----END PGP MESSAGE-----") in a text editor, save it as a file (i.e. mymessage.txt in your home folder).

You can decrypt that file using the command:

```
gpg --decrypt mymessage.txt
```

More info: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GnuPrivacyGuardHowto#Validation_on_Launchpad